# Redirect old url with several dirs to first level

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I've a lot of url with same estructure

```
/blog/<category>/item/<slug-article>
```

Such

```
/blog/administracion-sistemas-unix/item/named-run-gigante
```

I like create a rule to move a first level

```
https://<site>/<slug-article>
https://<site>/named-run-gigante
```

I not found any solution for this without create a rule for every category

Comment: The solution for me (I think there're a best way) `RedirectMatch 301 /blog/(.*)/item/(.*) /$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 /blog/(.*)/item/(.*) /$2
> ```

You seem to be along the right lines, however, this potentially matches "too much" (eg. multiple path segments, any characters, no slug at all, etc.). Generally, you should be as specific as possible. For instance, if your "category" and "slug-article" consist of only lowercase letters and hyphens then try something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/[a-z-]+/item/(.+) /$1
```

This includes a start of string anchor (`^`) so `/blog/...` must occur only at the start of the URL. Also removed the capturing group from the first subpattern - this is unnecessary since you only appear to need the "slug-article".

You'll need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

Note that if you have existing mod_rewrite directives (ie. you are using WordPress or other popular CMS) then you should use mod_rewrite instead, to avoid potential conflicts. For example, at the start of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/[a-z-]+/item/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]
```